# gcloud any command work only sometimes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Sometimes after I run some command lines such as `gcloud instances list`
the output is shown after 1 or 2 minutes, rarely after 5 minutes.

When I tried to run `gcloud instances ssh inst_name`, this is console output I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com
Please run:

$ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a different account:

$ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

Running either of those commands or both of them doesn't help.
Does someone know a workaround or root cause for my problem?

Comment: Have you tried [running](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) `gcloud compute ssh inst_name`? Could you please explain if you are getting any errors when running the commands related to authentication that are shown in the error?

Comment: You can use gcloud to do some diagnostic checks by running "gcloud info --run-diagnostics" (test your network etc), and what Rodrigo says, can you show the output from the "gcloud auth login" command?